# Matlab error in subs with polynomial

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a problem with matlab.
I have the following vector (19x1):

```
z_star = [0.0005 0.0008 0.0243 -12.3255 21.4029 -14.0085 4.7985 -0.9602 -0.1417 1.0886 -2.3934 2.9913 -2.3456 1.2184 -0.4282 0.1011 -0.0154 0.0014 -0.0001]';
```

Then:

```
tf = 2;
vec = [1,tf,tf^2,tf^3,tf^4,tf^5,tf^6,tf^7,tf^8,tf^9,tf^10,tf^11,tf^12,tf^13,tf^14,tf^15,tf^16,tf^17,tf^18];
```

If I compute:

```
 vec*z_star
```

the result is approximately 1.9995.

Then I write the following code:

```
syms b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9 b10 b11 b12 b13 b14 b15 b16 b17 b18 k
theta = b18*k^18+b17*k^17+b16*k^16+b15*k^15+b14*k^14+b13*k^13+b12*k^12+b11*k^11*b10*k^10+b9*k^9+b8*k^8+b7*k^7+b6*k^6+b5*k^5+b4*k^4+b3*k^3+b2*k^2+b1*k+b0;

N = 101;
t = linspace(0,tf,N);
theta = subs(theta,[b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,b13,b14,b15,b16,b17,b18],(z_star)');

theta = subs(theta,k,t);

theta = double(theta);
```

The result that I get for theta(N) is a really big negative number.

Shouldn't that be the same 1.9995 as before? Why is it different? 
Thank you.

Comment: tf = 3 to get 1.9995

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, I would rename `tf` to another variable as `tf` is a function used from the Control Systems toolbox that defines the transfer function of a system.  Let's called it something like `tf_num`.  Keeping `z_start` the same,  I would also like replace your `vec` call to this:

```
z_star = [0.0005 0.0008 0.0243 -12.3255 21.4029 -14.0085 4.7985 -0.9602 -0.1417 1.0886 -2.3934 2.9913 -2.3456 1.2184 -0.4282 0.1011 -0.0154 0.0014 -0.0001]';
tf_num = 2;
vec = (tf_num).^(0:18);
```

`vec` is the same as how you defined it previously, but we are doing it completely vectorized.  The above will define a vector where each element is `tf` to the power of 0, 1, 2, up to 18, which is what you defined originally.  It's a lot cleaner and easier to maintain.

Now, when I compute `vec*z_star`, I don't get 1.9995.  In fact, I get:

```
>> format long g;
>> vec*z_star

ans =

         -4.89990000000326
```

You should probably check how you computed the number again to be sure.

Now, the reason why you're not getting the same number is because you have a *slight* typo in your `theta` equation:

```
.... + b11*k^11*b10*k^10 ....
```

You have a multiplication in between the 11th power and 10th power... that should probably be a plus.

When I corrected that typo, and run your code, this is what I get:

```
%// From before
z_star = [0.0005 0.0008 0.0243 -12.3255 21.4029 -14.0085 4.7985 -0.9602 -0.1417 1.0886 -2.3934 2.9913 -2.3456 1.2184 -0.4282 0.1011 -0.0154 0.0014 -0.0001]';
tf_num = 2;
vec = (tf_num).^(0:18);

%// Your code
syms b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9 b10 b11 b12 b13 b14 b15 b16 b17 b18 k

%// Note - change in equation from above
theta = b18*k^18+b17*k^17+b16*k^16+b15*k^15+b14*k^14+b13*k^13+b12*k^12+b11*k^11+b10*k^10+b9*k^9+b8*k^8+b7*k^7+b6*k^6+b5*k^5+b4*k^4+b3*k^3+b2*k^2+b1*k+b0;

N = 101;
t = linspace(0,tf_num,N);
theta = subs(theta,[b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,b13,b14,b15,b16,b17,b18],(z_star)');

theta = subs(theta,k,t);    
theta = double(theta);
```

Now, if we display the last element of `theta`, we get:

```
>> theta(N)

ans =

         -4.89990000000002
```

Comment: I checked for typos ten times, but I hadn't seen that... Thank you very much for the answer!